# Alteryx Convert String to Time

Tags: time, types, type-conversion, alteryx

I have a column of times in ALteryx like the following:

```
Time
=====
8:05 AM
8:07 AM
8:11 AM
8:12 AM
8:16 AM
...
```

They are currently stored as a String, but I want to convert them to the Time format. So far, I have tried using the `LEFT` and `TRIM` function to isolate the time itself as such:

```
Trim(Left([Time], 5)," ")
```

However, when I try to convert this to a `Time` datatype, I receive type conversion errors. How can I convert something like **8:46 AM** from a String to a Time datatype in Alteryx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging and trying different things out, and I was able to figure it out. For the reference of others, here is what I did:

```
DateTimeParse([VisitTime] + " " + [PartofDay],"%I:%M %P")
```

Where `[VisitTime]` is the time expressed like `8:30` and `[PartofDay]` is `AM` or `PM`.

After this, I used a Select tile to change the datatype from String to Time without type conversion errors.